# 2d fourier based filter on odd image sizes

Tags: image-processing, filters, dft

I am trying to use

$$
f(x, y) (-1)^{x + y} \Leftrightarrow F(u - M/2, v - N/2)
$$

to post-process the result of a Fourier-based filter operation, like so

```cpp
engine.run<Dft::Direction::Backward>(size, input<0>(args), output_buffer.pixels().data());

auto sign_row = 1.0f;
for(uint32_t row = 0; row < size.height(); ++row)
{
    auto sign_col = 1.0f;
    for(uint32_t col = 0; col < size.width(); ++col)
    {
        output<0>(args, col, row) = output_buffer(col, row).real() * sign_col * sign_row;
        sign_col *= -1.0f;
    }
    sign_row *= -1.0f;
}
```

This makes it possible to skip flipping the filter mask.

It works perfectly for even width and height. However, if one is odd, the boundary condition is no longer periodic but 0 on at least one edge. I guess the problem is related to the fact that $M/2$ or $N/2$ is no longer an integer in this case. Going back to the more general case of

$$
f(x, y) \exp(j 2\pi(u_0 x/M + v_0y/N )) \Leftrightarrow F(u - u_0, v - v_0)
$$

$M$ and $N$ cancels out for a half-shift (or any other fraction) so I am not sure how to deal with this case.

This is what the mask looks like. It should be perfectly symmetric around the center.

[image: Filter mask]

Comment: I guess what makes possible to skip flipping the filter mask is the fact that it is symmetric.

Comment: @Bob and it is in both odd and even case. However, for the odd case, you have to cut through a pixel, so it is 0.5 pixels to the left and to the right.

Comment: Oh, you’re trying to avoid the circular shift (fftshift). Yeah, that’s a complex function for odd sizes. I don’t understand why you would replace moving data in memory in a simple pattern by multiplications. The multiplications are going to be more work, especially for odd sizes where the phase shift is not 180 degrees. You’re better off shifting and then computing a real-valued FFT, rather than a complex-valued FFT followed by a phase shift.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Moving data in memory is certainly more work than multiplying by ±1 unless you're on a computer from the early 90's, though DDR5 may somewhat reduce the memory bottleneck. You mean that I should use the fftw r2c and c2r functions instead of the c2c functions?

Comment: But you’re not just flipping a sign, you’re multiplying by a complex number because the phase shift is not 180 degrees for odd sizes. And it’s a different complex number for each pixel. Also, the moving data around can be done on one image line at the time, at the same time you compute the FFT for that line, so the data needs to be in cache anyway. It almost comes for free.

Comment: @CrisLuengo So you're suggesting that I should roll my own 2d fft based on 1d fft? How would that look?

Comment: I wouldn’t recommend rolling your own of anything unless it’s not already been done well before. FFTs have been done to death, you should use an existing implementation. There are some that have a flag for where the origin should be.

Comment: [I rolled my own nD FFT for DIPlib](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/master/src/transform/fourier.cpp), because I had some special requirements. This implementation does have the origin flag, it allows for different normalizations, has separate code paths for real and complex spatial domain, does proper multithreaded, and is based on either PocketFFT or FFTW depending on a compilation option. I would suggest you use DIPlib. https://diplib.org/

Comment: DIPlib comes with a function to compute convolutions through the FFT, don’t implement that yourself either unless you want to learn how it’s done. [`dip::ConvolveFT`](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/linear.html#dip-ConvolveFT-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-L-dip-String-CL-dip-String-CL-dip-String-CL-dip-StringArray-CL).

Comment: @CrisLuengo Interesting lib. Something to look into.